# How to benchmark on multi-core processors

Tags: assembly, benchmarking, performancecounter, microbenchmark, rdtsc

I am looking for ways to perform micro-benchmarks on multi-core processors.

**Context:**

At about the same time desktop processors introduced out-of-order execution that made performance hard to predict, they, perhaps not coincidentally, also introduced special instructions to get very precise timings. Example of these instructions are `rdtsc` on x86 and `rftb` on PowerPC. These instructions gave timings that were more precise than could ever be allowed by a system call, allowed programmers to micro-benchmark their hearts out, for better or for worse.

On a yet more modern processor with several cores, some of which sleep some of the time, the counters are not synchronized between cores. We are told that `rdtsc` is no longer safe to use for benchmarking, but I must have been dozing off when we were explained the alternative solutions.

**Question:**

Some systems may save and restore the performance counter and provide an API call to read the proper sum. If you know what this call is for any operating system, please let us know in an answer.

Some systems may allow to turn off cores, leaving only one running. I know Mac OS X Leopard does when the right Preference Pane is installed from the Developers Tools. Do you think that this make `rdtsc` safe to use again?

**More context:**

Please assume I know what I am doing when trying to do a micro-benchmark. If you are of the opinion that if an optimization's gains cannot be measured by timing the whole application, it's not worth optimizing, I agree with you, but

1. I cannot time the whole application until the alternative data structure is finished, which will take a long time. In fact, if the micro-benchmark were not promising, I could decide to give up on the implementation now;
2. I need figures to provide in a publication whose deadline I have no control over.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On OSX (ARM, Intel and PowerPC), you want to use `mach_absolute_time( )`:

```
#include <mach/mach_time.h>
#include <stdint.h>    

// Utility function for getting timings in nanoseconds.
double machTimeUnitsToNanoseconds(uint64_t mtu) {
    static double mtusPerNanosecond = 0.0;
    if (0.0 == mtusPerNanosecond) {
        mach_timebase_info_data_t info;
        if (mach_timebase_info(&info)) {
            // Handle an error gracefully here, whatever that means to you.
            // If you do get an error, something is seriously wrong, so
            // I generally just report it and exit( ).
        }
        mtusPerNanosecond = (double)info.numer / info.denom;
    }
    return mtu * mtusPerNanosecond;
}

// In your code:
uint64_t startTime = mach_absolute_time( );
// Stuff that you want to time.
uint64_t endTime = mach_absolute_time( );
double elapsedNanoseconds = machTimeUnitsToNanoseconds(endTime - startTime);
```

Note that there's no need to limit to one core for this.  The OS handles the fix-up required behind the scenes for `mach_absolute_time( )` to give meaninful results in a multi-core (and multi-socket) environment.

Comment: Thanks, I should be able to work it out from http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/qa/qa2004/qa1398.html , although I am very disappointed at the result of `man mach_absolute_time`.

Comment: @Pascal: That would be a good bug to report.  I posted some sample code that avoids the pointer casting in that note.

Comment: Note that this solution will suffer from the probe effect much more than pinning your process to a single core and using rtdsc twice (on x86, can't speak for PowerPC). The compiler may not inline your functions, they'll take up more instruction cache, and you're doing multiplies and divides which I believe can vary in how long they take to complete based on their operands. 'rtdsc' just reads a register and so is much cheaper and will affect your results less.

Comment: @JosephGarvin: you can't just do a naked `rtdsc`, as it may execute out-of-order before (some of) the operations you are trying to measure.  At a minimum, you need to do `cpuid` before it.  `mach_absolute_time( )` takes care of those details for you (and removes the need for pinning as well, making it a *much* simpler solution for ordinary use).  The overhead that it introduces is quite small; if you're timing events that take more than few thousand cycles, it's perfectly adequate.  If you actually look at the code I listed, the multiplies and divides happen outside of the code being timed.

Comment: @StephenCanon: Oops. Based on its name I thought mach_absolute_time was going to try to give a real time, I didn't realize it's just a pass through to rdtsc (absolute to me means calendar time, relative would mean relative to machine startup). And of course you're right about the multiplies/divides just being in the conversion afterwards ;p

Answer (score 1):

The cores are returning the correct synced values for "rtdsc". If you have a multisocket machine you have to fix the processe to one socket. This is not the problem.

The main problem is that the scheduler is making the data unreliable. 
There is some performance API for Linux Kernel > 2.6.31 but i haven't looked at it.
Windows > Vista is doing a great job here, use QueryThreadCycleTime and QueryProcessCycleTime.

I'm not sure about OSX but AFAIK "mach_absolute_time" does not adjust the scheduled time.